# ip address/ifconfig show different ip address

Tags: networking, ip

I created a software by using yocto for my beagleboneblack.

I have noticed that the `ip address` command shows different IP addresses when I call it on the host (ubuntu) 192.168.0.1 and when I call it on beaglebone 192.168.0.100.

Why are there two IP addresses?

edit:
my mistake, couldnt explain it better.
after i connect a linux device to my pc, when i write "ifconfig" i thought i will see ip of connected device.

As i understood, it shows how connected device see me.

Comment: You have 2 different systems? Why on earth do you think they should have the same IP address?

Comment: Is your question about `ifconfig` or not??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each host has to have its own unique ip address on a lan.

If both of them had the same IP, that would be an ip conflict, and the two machines would not be able to talk to each other, and other network operations would be unreliable as the two interfered with each other.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/check-ip-address-in-linux):
`ifconfig` and `ip address` commands should display the same IP address in the same server.

A Linux server can have more than one network interface. This is often the case with web servers and other devices that need to be able to connect to different networks. For example, a web server may need to be able to connect to both the internet and a local network.

A network interface can have more than one IP address. The first address is called the primary address, while the others are called secondary addresses or aliases. Using secondary IP addresses is common with web servers. These IP addresses are different.

Comment: The answer is from [here](https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/check-ip-address-in-linux).